# SAPUI5 table in list

Tags: sapui5

I have a view:

```
<List
        items="{data>/Stages}">
           <CustomListItem>
            <Panel>
                <headerToolbar>
                     <Toolbar>
                         <content>
                           <Button
                              visible="{= ${data>/Stages/length} > 1}" />
                         </content>
                     </Toolbar>
                 </headerToolbar>
                 <content>
                 <Table
                   growing="true" 
                   growingScrollToLoad="false"
                   items="{
                       path: 'data>FieldWorks',
                       templateShareable: true
                   }"
                   class="blueTable originTable techTable">
                   <columns>
                     <Column
                       visible="true"
                       vAlign="Middle" 
                       width="15px" />
                   </columns>
                   <items>
                     <ColumnListItem>
                         <cells>
                          <core:Icon
                              visible="{ ???}"
                              src="sap-icon://customfont/moving"
                              size="2.1rem"
                              color="#14c6c9" />
                         </cells>
                     </ColumnListItem>
                  </items>
               </Table>
            </content>
        </Panel>
    </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

I have a model (example):

```
data: {
   Stages: [{
       FieldWorks: [{}, ....]
    }, .....]
}
```

I hide my button (in my toolBar) by expression binding as you can see.
What is the best way to hide my Icon (in CustomListItem) by condition FieldWorks.length > 1

Comment: Did you try something to get this? Or you get any error?
A similar way of expression binding might help you or a formatter?

Comment: I thought about external formatter, but it doesn't seem nice to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a JSON Model just add boolean property to your JSONModel to the FieldWorks entity and bind the visible property to it. Then one time you have to set it when data is loaded  or created and that's it.

Comment: The trouble is i can modify my data (add\remove FieldWorks) and maintain this boolean can be solution but it doesn't seem nice to me

Comment: I changed my mind your solution seems pretty good for me. I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new property in your json Model under the FieldWorks property  in order to bind the visibility of the icon.

you can use Object.defineProperty ([SPEC MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)) to define your calculated new property.